# HTTPS connections fail with Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, connection, https

Currently I can't use HTTPS **with Chrome***. I get

> Error 103 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED)

I noticed it trying to login into Dropbox or search with Google using HTTPS.

How can I repair this?

<sub>* It works with Internet Explorer. Must be something specifically Chrome related.</sub>

Comment: Which OS are you having this problem on? Do other web browsers on the same computer work?

Comment: Windows7. Internet Explorer works.

Comment: Are you using a proxy by chance?

Comment: No, no proxy using here.

Comment: Check if your date and time is set correctly.

Comment: @gronostaj: It is set correctly.

Comment: Funny, because searching for the error message on Google gives a lot of results. Maybe, it could be a good place to start for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be (frequently is) a problem due to recent updates to your antivirus software.  Recently (late-Feb '13) [this happened](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/HEfvBmJkTsI/discussion) to a lot of users of Kaspersky.

I would suggest closing Chrome, disabling your Antivirus, and opening Chrome again to test.

Comment: You are awesome. That's it. What can I do about it (besides deactivating my Kaspersky Antivirus)?

Comment: From what people are reporting, it may just work if you reenable Kaspersky.  Past that, I'd try possibly removing and reinstalling Kaspersky.  Someone else suggested adding exceptions for sites you use [here](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/HEfvBmJkTsI/IbcaomjozTEJ).  Hope that helps.

Comment: Reactivating Kaspersky did not work. I can't deinstall it. I can't touch it because of a company-enforced Windows Domain Policy. But I keep looking...

Comment: Deactivating the checkbox *Activate Web control* in Kaspersky's options did make it work again. For now that is good enough for me till Kaspersky brings an update.

Comment: Oh hey, no worries. :)  Just glad you've got something workable.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that a firewall or Antivirus is blocking Chrome. You should add Chrome to the exceptions list.